# If $A\overline{A}$ is normal, then $A\overline{A}, \overline{A^*A}, AA^*$ commute.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_n$ and suppose that $A\overline{A}$ is normal. How to prove that the matrices  $B = A\overline{A}, C=\overline{A^*A}, D=AA^*$ commute? Here $\cdot^*$ is the conjugate transpose.

So far I have deduced the following facts:

1. If $AB^*$ and $B^*A$ are normal, then $BA^*A = AA^*B$ using Fuglede-Putnam (FP)
2. $A\overline{A}$ is normal iff $AA^*A^\top = A^\top A^*A$.

For $B$ and $D$ it is straightforward:
$$
DB^*=AA^*(A\overline{A})^*=AA^*A^\top A^*=A^\top A^*AA^*=(A\overline{A})^*AA^*=B^*D \implies DB=BD
$$
using 2. and FP. For $C$ and the $D$ the closest I could do is:
$$
DC=AA^*A^\top\overline{A}=A^\top A^*A\overline{A}=(A\overline{A})^*A\overline{A}=A\overline{A}(A\overline{A})^*=A\overline{A}A^\top A^*,
$$
and for the others I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out:
$$
CD = \overline{A^*A}AA^* = A^\top\overline{A}AA^*=(A^\top A^*A)^\top A^*=(AA^*A^\top)^\top A^* = A\overline{A}A^\top A^*,
$$
using 2. and the rest of the calculation is done in the question.

Finally,
$$
BC = A\overline{A}A^\top\overline{A}=(AA^*A^\top)^\top\overline{A}=(A^\top A^*A)^\top \overline{A}=A^\top\overline{A}A\overline{A}=CB.
$$